# Process Specific Section in a text file from python

Tags: python-3.x

I Have 3 Files With 4 Sections (Example)

```
File 1                          File 2                    File 3

Section 1                       Section 1                 Section 1
----------                      ----------                ----------
Data 1                          Data 1                    Data 1



Section 2                       Section 2                 Section 2
----------                      ----------                ----------
Data 2                          Data 2                    Data 2



Section 3                       Section 3                 Section 3         
----------                      ----------                ----------
Data 3                          Data 3                    Data 3



Section 4                       Section 4                 Section 4 
----------                      ----------                ----------
Data 4                          Data 4                    Data 4
```

And I Want To Append Only Section 2 To A New File.
Any Ideas how to do it?

```
Output:
NewFile
Data 2 Of File 1
Data 2 Of File 2
Data 2 Of File 3
etc... (If I have more files)
```

Thank You

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your code and mention what is the problem you are facing

Comment: i haven't tried any code yet because i don't know